# Trying to have my featured images post in a loop if they are set

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a custom post type set up right now with each posts allowing up to 6 featured images to be added. I want to loop through the 6 featured images and generate the HTML IF there is featured image there.

Here is the snippet of code I am having a little bit of trouble with. I was thinking that I would be able to just echo it out but it still will generate the tag on other posts that don't have the extra featured images. Here is the place I am trying to get it to work: http://testing.bdanzer.com/tabs/ I am just trying to load the small thumbnail images on the posts on the drop down. The big image is just for the first thumbnail. I am just having a problem loading 2-6 if that makes sense.

```
<div class="bdanzer-thumbnails">

    <?php
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) { //if a thumbnail has been set
        //get the id of the featured image
        $imgID = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID); 

        //get the url of the featured image (returns an array)
        $featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgID, 'full'); 

        $imgURL = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(),
        'feature-image-2', NULL, 'large');

        echo '<img src="' . $imgURL . '"/>';
    }

    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You may find [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89202/query-posts-only-with-featured-image) helpful.

Comment: I believe a for each loop should do what you need. If the info is being pulled from a database or an array, you would need to iterate through them. Hopefully I understand your question correctly

Comment: @ObsidianAge The problem with that post is that I am trying to see if it has a post thumbnail for up to 6 of them. I have 6 featured images for the post type. With the ids "feature-image-(2 through 6)"